# What graphic cards do Android emulator GPU emulation support?

Tags: android-emulator, hardware-acceleration

I have HD7690M XT (an overclocked version of 6770M) and Android emulator (sdk tool rev.20) for ICS failed to start hardware OpenGL ES emulation with the following error message:

> emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: Could not load DLL!
>   emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

and with software renderer I got really bad color resolution (please see the attached screenshots). I suspect that this is due to the software renderer (no such problem in emulating earlier versions of Android). Have someone who can run hardware emulation seen this problem?

[image]

[image]

What graphic cards can hardware GPU emulation run on? (You can see detailed debug messages by executing `$ emulator -avd your_avd_name -verbose`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Windows 7 (64-bit) machine. The reason was that the `libOpenglRender.DLL` could not be located. I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib` to the `PATH` variable and can start the emulator now without error message. However, I don't see a difference in quality of the graphics compared to your screenshot.

Comment: thanks for your input! the DLL loading error is gone. However i cannot check whether the color issue got resolved because somehow the emulator failed to run right now...

Comment: I added this to my path but i can still see (using Procmon) that its trying to load this file from tools folder and not tools\lib.

Comment: did you place the intended path before the other one?

Answer (score 7):

Copy the file below from SDK\tools\lib to SDK\tools.

1. libEGL_translator.dll
2. libGLES_CM_translator.dll
3. libGLES_V2_translator.dll
4. libOpenglRender.dll

Answer (score 6):

Copy all the dll files from tools\lib to tools.

Comment: This worked for me, whereas the other solution of adding to PATH did not. I copied libOpenglRender.dll, libEGL_translator.dll, libGLES_CM_translator.dll and libGLES_V2_translator.dll Thanks!

Comment: Same here.  The PATH solution didn't work for me, but this did.

Answer (score 1):

Add toos\lib to PATH works, the only thing you need to remember is to add it in the HEAD of the PATH, not the end.
Check this post:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33336